# Could not resolve all files for configuration ':firebase_core:detachedConfiguration1'

Tags: android, firebase, gradle

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nYz7C.png)` What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':firebase_core:extractDebugAnnotations'.

> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':firebase_core:detachedConfiguration1'.
> Could not download intellij-core-30.3.0.jar (com.android.tools.external.com-intellij:intellij-core:30.3.0)
> Could not get resource 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/external/com-intellij/intellij-core/30.3.0/intellij-core-30.3.0.jar'.
> Tag mismatch!
> Could not download kotlin-compiler-30.3.0.jar (com.android.tools.external.com-intellij:kotlin-compiler:30.3.0)
> Could not get resource 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/external/com-intellij/kotlin-compiler/30.3.0/kotlin-compiler-30.3.0.jar'.
> Tag mismatch!
> Could not download groovy-3.0.9.jar (org.codehaus.groovy:groovy:3.0.9)
> Could not get resource 'https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/codehaus/groovy/groovy/3.0.9/groovy-3.0.9.jar'.
> Tag mismatch
> `

`I was enabling google_sign_in and after pasting json in my reddit clone using firebase I tried checking is my app running or not.Then the series of error arised. Please help me resolve it` 
include ":app"`

Comment: On Stack Overflow, please [don't show pictures of text and code](https://overflow.tips/write-good-question/formatting-text-code#dont-use-screenshots-of-text). Copy the text into the question itself and format it so that it's easy to read, copy, and search. You can edit the question to correct this using the edit link at the bottom.